# Custom CSS in WordPress is not served over HTTPS breaking WooCommerce secure checkout

Tags: wordpress, https, woocommerce

I use WooCommerce on my WordPress site and I have just forced HTTPS redirect for the Checkout flow. However, when I do this, my custom CSS is blocked. I get:

> Mixed Content: The page at `https://www.example.co.uk/blog/product/myProduct/` was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet `http://www.example.co.uk/blog/?sccss=1&ver=fe62ddea3ed1898e6866564ccdc86c01`. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

My custom CSS is produced by [the simple custom CSS](https://github.com/johnregan3/simple-custom-css) plugin.

How can I fix this / work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your plugin seems to not recognize, that the whole site runs https.

about one hour ago new 3.3 version of your plugin was published - one of the announced news is the support of https. try to update.